# knit2html put .md in specified path

Tags: r, knitr

In this following MWE on a Windows 7 machine running R 3.12

I am trying to create an md file from an Rmd.  It creates the md file in my working directory, not int he specified path.  The HTML file is created in the specified path instead.  How can I make the md get created in `deleteMe/my.md`?

**## Create  a minimal Rmd:**

```
dir.create("deleteMe")

cat("\nminimal", file = "deleteMe/my.Rmd")
```

**## knit it to md**

```
knitr::knit2html(input = "deleteMe/my.Rmd",  output = "deleteMe/my.md")
```

**## If I set the working directory to deleteME it is correct but I'm don't like to use setwd in functions**

```
setwd("deleteMe")
knitr::knit2html(input = "deleteMe/my.Rmd",  output = "deleteMe/my.md")
```

I realize it's a `knit2html`, not `knit2md`, but it creates an md as well.  I'm open to other functions/packages/methods if this is the wrong approach.  I do not want a yaml though as this is for a README.md creation that I don't want the yaml to appear in.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of `knit2html()`, you can see that when it calls `knit()`, it doesn't specify `output=`. That means that `knit()` is assuming you want the .md created in the working directory (hence why it works when you change working directory).

Creating a new version of `knit2html()` makes it work:

```
knit2html2 <- function (input, output = NULL, ..., envir = parent.frame(), 
          text = NULL, quiet = FALSE, encoding = getOption("encoding")) 
{
#Specify output path in knit()
  out = knit(input, output, text = text, envir = envir, encoding = encoding, 
             quiet = quiet)
  if (is.null(text)) {
    output = knitr:::sub_ext(if (is.null(output) || is.na(output)) 
      out
      else output, "html")
    markdown::markdownToHTML(out, output, encoding = encoding, 
                             ...)
    invisible(output)
  }
  else markdown::markdownToHTML(text = out, ...)
}
```

It seems reasonable that `output=` be passed on to `knit()` - maybe a pull request is in order